# AWS architecture: route job to pool of workers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, architecture, amazon-sqs

I have this scenario:

1. there is an S3 bucket where files are dropped.
2. When a file is dropped, a lambda function is fired which does something.
3. I want some operation to occur for each file dropped, and these operations should be handled by a pool of workers.

I think lambdas are not the best solution for workers, as they would spawn without control, so maybe instead I could have the lambdas post messages to a queue and have a fixed number of workers (the pool) reading messages asynchronously from it. Maybe just SQS would be sufficient. As for the workers, any technology that can read from SQS would do the trick, as long as I can specify the number of simultaneous readers (pool size).

Any comments about this solution?

Comment: Send the S3 events to SQS queue, and have a Lambda function that processes the queue is the perfect solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

This concern about over-spawning of lambda-based workers is quite common. It is also known that lambda-based workers can easily:

- Overrun & kill downstream APIs they depend on.
- Hit rate limits that could cause data to be lost in-between.
- Get their credentials blocked due to sudden spike of activities.

A common solution to this is the use of `ReservedConcurrentExecutions` property that limits the amount of concurrent lambdas that could run at a given time.

For applications that need higher throughput, an organization can usually resort to :

- Scaling of downstream APIs
- Changing the data direction model from cloud-based workers **pushing** data to downstream systems to a model where `downstream systems pull the data from the cloud instead`.